# How do I find the latest DateTime for each of my products in combination with another condition

Tags: sql

```
Product:
ProductID
ProductName

StateLog:
StateLogID
ProductID (Foreign Key)
State (bit)
TimeStamp (DateTime)
```

I need to find the highest StateLog.TimeStamp for each StateLog.ProductID there have the StateLog.State = 0

Comment: @Mark Byers, based on "datetime" in the question, I'm guessing TSQL, either Sybase or SQL Server, with SQL Server being the most likely.

Comment: Sorry for not pointing that out Mark. Its SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT
    p.ProductID, p.ProductName, dt.MaxTimeStamp
    FROM Product p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                            ProductID, MAX(TimeStamp) AS MaxTimeStamp
                            FROM StateLog
                            WHERE State = 0
                            GROUP BY ProductID
                        ) dt ON p.ProductID =dt.ProductID 
    ORDER BY p.ProductName
```

or just:

```
SELECT
   ProductID, MAX(TimeStamp) AS MaxTimeStamp
   FROM StateLog
   WHERE State = 0
   GROUP BY ProductID
```

Comment: Thx for adding the extra alternative, because I also needed that, and forgot to ask for it.

Both works very good.

Comment: Hi, I have a new SQL challenge/problem if your up for it? :)

See my lastest question if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH ProductTimeStamps AS
(
   SELECT ProductID, Max(TimeStamp) FROM SateLog WHERE State=0 GROUP BY ProductID
)
SELECT sl.StateLogID, sl.ProductID, sl.TimeStamp
FROM StateLog sl
INNER JOIN ProductTimeStamps pts ON pts.ProductID = sl.ProductID AND pts.TimeStamp = sl.TimeStamp
WHERE sl.State = 0
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. What is ProductTimeStramps? I've never seen a 'WITH' before. It looks interesting and I want to run your solution also. Sorry if it's obvious.

Comment: It's called a Common Table Expression (CTE).  Supported by Oracle and Sql Server 2005 or later, but not mysql.  You could easily just write it as an uncorrelated derived table (subquery) instead.